# Getting all classes and all methods in a class via JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am using C++ along with JNI with the goal of listing all the methods in a given Java class and listing all class names in a given java application. I was trying to do the following to get Minecrafts main class but it's not working correctly, and I want to figure out how I can debug it in order to fix it myself. To do that I will need to be able to list all classes. This will then make debugging any other issues a lot easier.

```
static jobject classLoader;
static jmethodID mid_findClass;

static void setupClassLoader()
{
    jclass c_Thread = Java::Env->FindClass("java/lang/Thread");
    jclass c_Map = Java::Env->FindClass("java/util/Map");
    jclass c_Set = Java::Env->FindClass("java/util/Set");
    jclass c_ClassLoader = Java::Env->FindClass("java/lang/ClassLoader");

    jmethodID mid_getAllStackTraces = Java::Env->GetStaticMethodID(c_Thread, "getAllStackTraces", "()Ljava/util/Map;");
    jmethodID mid_keySet = Java::Env->GetMethodID(c_Map, "keySet", "()Ljava/util/Set;");
    jmethodID mid_toArray = Java::Env->GetMethodID(c_Set, "toArray", "()[Ljava/lang/Object;");
    jmethodID mid_getContextClassLoader = Java::Env->GetMethodID(c_Thread, "getContextClassLoader", "()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;");
    mid_findClass = Java::Env->GetMethodID(c_ClassLoader, "findClass", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;");
    jmethodID mid_currentThread = Java::Env->GetStaticMethodID(c_Thread, "currentThread", "()Ljava/lang/Thread;");

    jobject obj_stackTracesMap = Java::Env->CallStaticObjectMethod(c_Thread, mid_getAllStackTraces);
    jobject obj_threadsSet = Java::Env->CallObjectMethod(obj_stackTracesMap, mid_keySet);

    jobjectArray threads = (jobjectArray) Java::Env->CallObjectMethod(obj_threadsSet, mid_toArray);
    jint szThreads = Java::Env->GetArrayLength(threads);

    for (int i = 0; i < szThreads; i++) {
        jobject thread = Java::Env->GetObjectArrayElement(threads, i);
        jobject classLoaderObj = Java::Env->CallObjectMethod(thread, mid_getContextClassLoader);

        if (classLoaderObj) { // How can I print all class names here instead of using NewStringUTF with a class name I presume to exist
            jstring className = Java::Env->NewStringUTF("minecraft.client.Minecraft");
            jobject minecraftClass = Java::Env->CallObjectMethod(classLoaderObj, mid_findClass, className);

            if (minecraftClass) { // This is never true 
                classLoader = classLoaderObj;

                Java::Env->DeleteLocalRef(minecraftClass);

                break;
            }
        }

        Java::Env->DeleteLocalRef(thread);
    }
```

Alright assuming I get the above issue fixed by figuring out how I can print classes and then manage to get the right class I will need to be able to print methods of a class out with their names and return types. The following is my apprach but I have no idea how I would go about actually printing all method info from a jClass object.

```
inline static jclass clazz;

Java::AssignClass("example.Example", clazz);

bool Java::AssignClass(std::string name, jclass& out)
{
    jstring className = Java::Env->NewStringUTF(name.c_str());
    jobject findClass = Java::Env->CallObjectMethod(classLoader, mid_findClass, className);

    if (findClass) {
        out = (jclass) findClass;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: A `jclass` object is literally a reference to a `java.lang.Class` object, so you can just invoke `getMethods` and `getFields` on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> listing all the methods in a given Java class

Use Java reflection.  [`java.lang.Class.getMethods()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods--) will give you the *public* methods of the class represented by the `Class` object it is invoked upon, including inherited ones.  [`java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods--) will get you *all* the methods of any visibility declared directly by target class.  Between these two, and maybe `Class.getSuperclass()`, you can identify all the methods of any class of interest.

You can invoke those methods via JNI, but the JNI API does not have its own functions for accomplishing the same thing.

> listing all class names in a given java application

You can list or extract the contents of the relevant JAR files to find the names of the classes within.  Their package names may give you an idea of which are of the most interest.  There is no good Java API, however, for programmatically getting an exhaustive list of known or available classes.  JNI certainly does not provide such.

> I was trying to [use the context ClassLoaders of the live threads] to get Minecrafts main class

That's a plausible approach, supposing that you know the fully-qualified name of the class you want to find.  But it's not a sure thing.  There are fun `ClassLoader` games that could be played to prevent a given class or group of classes from being accessed that way.  Not that I think it likely that Minecraft plays such games, but it's not out of the question.

However, you are already retrieving stack traces of all the threads, and if Minecraft's initial thread is still running then you can get the name of the game's entry point class from the last element of the stack trace of that thread.  If there are multiple threads then you may not know which to look at, but for debugging purposes, that would give you a short list to consider.

> I will need to be able to list all classes.

For some definition of "all", I guess.  But even with a fairly restrictive definition, this is not something you can ordinarily obtain from a `ClassLoader`.  I would find another way.

Comment: How can JNI get a class without having knowledge of all the classes? What sort of "games" can be played to mitigate this way of getting jclasses? Also, how would you suggest me going about "you can get the name of the game's entry point class from the last element of the stack trace of that thread. If there are multiple threads then you may not know which to look at, but for debugging purposes, that would give you a short list to consider" because I know the normal name path of the class well at least but for some reason its not working.

Comment: @UnSure, JNI knows how to *find* a class that is in the classpath, given its name.  Similarly, any Java `ClassLoader` can tell you whether it knows about a class by a given name that you specify to it.  But neither can give you a list of all the available classes.  The concept is not even well defined, because classes can be defined on the fly.  More generally, existing class definitions don't have to be listable, or enumerable.  For instance, they can, in principle, be loaded over the network from a remote server.

Comment: @UnSure, if you are confident that you know the name of the class you want then you don't need to try to figure it out from the stack traces, but your question gave me the impression that you were not certain you did.  At minimum, the stack traces might help you confirm what you (think you) already know.  Do consult the API docs `Thread.getAllStackTraces()` and the associated classes for information about how you could obtain class and method names for the currently-running methods.

Comment: As far as ClassLoader games, an application can equip threads with a custom or carefully-configured `ClassLoader`s that has a restricted view of the available classes, for example.  Again, it is unlikely that Minecraft is doing something like this.

Comment: Here is the thing it works on some Minecraft clients but not all which leads me to believe some tricks may have been done here but how can I get the thread stack trace from JNI?

Comment: @UnSure, what do you mean "how can I get the thread stack trace from JNI"?  You are already doing it!  What else do you think your call to `Thread.getAllStackTraces()` does?  Did you not write that code?

Comment: Yea but how do I use it to gain information on my situation so I can determine what the problem is?

Comment: @UnSure the question that I suggested you could answer by looking at the stack traces is "What is the name of the game's entry point class?"  If the main thread is still running then the last element of that thread's stack trace will indicate the `main` method and the name of that class.  More generally, I expect that you can get the names of several important classes from the latter elements of your stack traces.

Comment: I would just like some next steps to take to debug this so I can get it working. I am looking at the decompiled Minecraft code and to get the main class you start at the minecraft package then client package then get the class. This does work like I said but when I try it on other minecraft clients it does not work which is why I assume the path is changed but I have no idea how to get the new path sine theres no source available.

Comment: I'm sorry, @UnSure, but you seem to keep moving the goalposts.  I have already answered the several questions posed in the original post.  I think that should suggest some next steps, and in these comments I have explicitly recommended variations on at least one: look at the details of the stack traces you are obtaining.  As far as I am concerned, **that answers the question posed**.  Nevertheless, I have also added the [minecraft] tag to the question, for perhaps that will draw someone with expertise more specific to your problem.

Comment: Yea I mean sure I can accept your answer, but I still am in the same spot I started. You are saying "look at the details of your stack trace" but I don't know how. I have ``jmethodID mid_getAllStackTraces`` and ``jobject obj_stackTracesMap`` but I am not sure how to gain any useful info from this. I don't need anyone to tell me the correct class paths I just need to figure out how I can debug it so I can find names on my own, which I still am not sure how to do.

Comment: @UnSure, you have presented some moderately complex JNI code as if it was your own, but it's hard to reconcile that with the appearance that you don't seem to know JNI very well.  Or maybe it's just that you don't know where to find or how to navigate [Java API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getAllStackTraces--)? I'm having trouble advising you because I don't understand where the barrier is.